# Linux repositories. Ubuntu apt-get and centOS yum

Tags: linux, centos7, yum, apt, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to VPS and when I want to install something in Ubuntu16.04 or CentOS7 I need to google it and hope it's written somewhere how to install it through apt-get or yum and then hope it is a good repository. Then even the same project has differences between those 2. For example you have httpd in yum and apache2 in apt-get ( it's not just the name they are different ).

Is there some sort of github where I can check reputation of repositories, official documentation on how to install and so on? Or is it something I will need to learn by trial and error?

Comment: First look in the distro repository for that release.  If present, then use that.  If not, read the docs project/vendor web site.  Most will suggest install method for popular distros like ubuntu/centos.  Past that, there is nothing 'official', and you have to do your own research.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example, let's say I would like to install apache on centOS. Is there any website or a way to do it in the console with yum to be fairly sure that I am installing the correct thing?

Comment: I am more of a Debian/Ubuntu user myself. But I would start with a `yum search apache`, it seems pretty likely that is going to be included in the default repo.

Comment: For CentOS you can consider one more repository official - the EPEL: fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

The EPEL repo provides packages which are not included in the official RHEL/CentOS repo. However it's maintained by RH/Fedora people.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in repositories will always be trusted/trustworthy.

Debian based (Ubuntu) and RedHat (CentOS) based are indeed different.

Even professionals still have to web-search.

You can try finding packages available with commands like `apt-cache search` and `yum search`.

basic examples:

`apt-cache search "http server"
yum search "http server"`

better examples:

`apt-cache search httpd | grep "HTTP [Ss]erver\|[Ww]eb.*[Ss]erver"
apt-cache showpkg httpd | awk '/Pa/, /Reverse P/ {next} {print $1 | "sort -u"}'
yum provides webserver`

You may prefer `aptitude` over `apt-*`.  For example you can both search and install with aptitude: `aptitude search apache2` and `aptitude install apache2`.

Sometimes you want to find out more information: `yum groupinfo "Web Server"` or `yum info httpd` or `aptitude show apache2`.

You are correct to realize that it will be much trial and error, and many web-searches.